# Can't get Google Spreadsheets QUERY to work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google spreadsheet, which has a long list of names. I want to filter the names who are blacklisted to another sheet/page with QUERY.

```
=QUERY(Buve!A:T;"A,B,Q,C,E,D,F,G,H,J,K; where S=blacklist")")"
```

This the formula I'm using, but it doesn't work and the spreadsheet says `formula analysis error`. Could anyone help me finding the issue here?

I've tried messing around with the brackets and etc. But couldn't find a solution for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
=QUERY(Buve!A:T; "A,B,Q,C,E,D,F,G,H,J,K where S='blacklist'")
```